# error handling, map_err and error type conversion

Tags: rust, error-handling

I'm learning rust and I'm currently working on the exercise [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/error_handling/errors6.rs).

So far I've come up with the following:

```
impl ParsePosNonzeroError {
   ...
   ...
   fn from_parseint(err: ParseIntError) -> ParsePosNonzeroError {
       ParsePosNonzeroError::ParseInt(err)
   }
```

```
fn parse_pos_nonzero(s: &str)
-> Result<PositiveNonzeroInteger, ParsePosNonzeroError>
{
     let x: i64 = s.parse::<i64>().map_err(ParsePosNonzeroError::from_parseint);
     PositiveNonzeroInteger::new(x).map_err(ParsePosNonzeroError::from_creation)
}
```

When I do this I get the error message:

```
! Compiling of exercises/error_handling/errors6.rs failed! Please try again. Here's the output:
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> exercises/error_handling/errors6.rs:34:18
   |
34 |       let x: i64 = s.parse::<i64>()
   |  ____________---___^
   | |            |
   | |            expected due to this
35 | |         .map_err(ParsePosNonzeroError::from_parseint);
   | |_____________________________________________________^ expected `i64`, found enum `Result`
   |
   = note: expected type `i64`
              found enum `Result<i64, ParsePosNonzeroError>`
```

Going through the documentation of `map_err` I see the following:
`Maps a Result<T, E> to Result<T, F> by applying a function to a contained Err value, leaving an Ok value untouched.`

What am I missing? Why is this not working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map_err` is returning a `Result<i64, ParsePosNonzeroError>` but you're trying to affect it to `x`, which you declared as an `i64` variable. You need to add a `?` so that an `Err` result will be returned and an `Ok` result will be unwrapped: `let x = s.parse::<i64>().map_err(ParsePosNonzeroError::from_parseint)?;`

Answer (score 3):

Also in complement to Jmb's answer, note that `?` already does what you're doing by hand here:

```
foo?
```

desugars to, more or less<sup>1</sup>,

```
match foo {
    Ok(foo) => foo,
    Err(e) => return Err(From::from(e));
}
```

So you can just [`impl From<ParseIntError> for ParsePosNonzeroError`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) , and `?` will perform the conversion implicitly, based on the divergence between the error type of `parse` and the one of `parse_pos_nonzero`.

---

<sup>1: it's a bit more complicated with the `Try` trait, but good enough for basic use</sup>